# Query with current date and time

Tags: sharepoint-server, query

I've built the following query to retrieve articles in Sharepoint:

```
(-PublishingExpirationDate<yesterday OR EmptyEndDate:0) 
(PublishingStartDate<2015-09-29 OR EmptyStartDate:0)
```

I read the syntax reference, but didn't find what I need:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff394606.aspx

Is there a method to replace a hard coded date with today's date and time, instead of 'today', 'yesterday' or a date?

Comment: You don't want to use `TODAY` ?

Comment: I am looking for a solution with date and (especially) time

Comment: Are you looking for something to get current time(eg: now ), instead of Today?

Comment: @Unnie Yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through KQL it is only possible to query by day ranges ie `Today`,`yesterday` etc. If you want to tune it further to limit results by exact current time, then you will have to use FQL instead. See this [blog](http://techmikael.blogspot.in/2013/07/limiting-search-results-by-exact-time.html) on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KQL syntax to include "today" in your query to get today's date.

afaik, there is no term for the current time.

REF: KQL Syntax https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx